# Tensorflow model doesn't reduce loss value on MNIST example

Tags: tensorflow, data-loss

I'm trying Tensorflow and tried to re-write a simple MNIST example with minor changes. I expect to see a reduction in the value of loss function after running the code while this does not happen.
I compared my code to many examples but was not able to figure out the problem.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 100

# Data Placeholders
t = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='IfTrain_placeholder')                                                     # if we are in training phase
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 28, 28, 1], name='Data_placeholder')
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None], name='Label_placeholder')

# Use Datasets to manage data
X_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
y_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

X_iter = X_data.make_initializable_iterator()
X_batch = X_iter.get_next()

y_iter = y_data.make_initializable_iterator()
y_batch = y_iter.get_next()

oh_y = tf.one_hot(indices=y_batch, depth=10)

# Model structure here
c1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=X_batch, 
                      filters=32, 
                      kernel_size=[5,5], 
                      padding='same', 
                      activation=tf.nn.relu, 
                      name='CNN1')

m1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=c1, 
                             pool_size=[2,2], 
                             strides=2, 
                             padding='same',
                             name='MaxPool1')

c2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=m1, 
                      filters=64, 
                      kernel_size=[5,5], 
                      padding='same', 
                      activation=tf.nn.relu, 
                      name='CNN2')

m2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=c2, 
                             pool_size=[2,2], 
                             strides=2, 
                             padding='same', 
                             name='MaxPool2')

f1 = tf.reshape(tensor=m2, shape=[-1, 7*7*64], name='Flat1')

d1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=f1, 
                     units=1024, 
                     activation=tf.nn.softmax, 
                     name='Dense1')

dr1 = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=d1, rate=0.4, training=t, name='Dropout1')

d2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dr1, 
                     units=10, 
                     activation=tf.nn.softmax, 
                     name='Dense2')

# Loss and otimization
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=oh_y, logits=d2)
classes = tf.argmax(input=d2, axis=1, name='ArgMax1')

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003, name='GD1')
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(), name='Optimizer1')

# Get data
mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
X_train = np.reshape(mnist.train.images, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
y_train = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
X_test = np.reshape(mnist.test.images, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
y_test = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)

# Run session
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)

  sess.run(X_iter.initializer, feed_dict={X:X_train})
  sess.run(y_iter.initializer, feed_dict={y:y_train})

  while True:
    try:
      out = sess.run({'accuracy': accuracy, 'loss': loss, 'train optimizer': train_op}, feed_dict={t:True})

  print(out['loss'])
except:
  break
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me find the problem.

Comment: Remove the softmax activation from both dense layers. You can use e.g. relu in the first dense layer but the second should have no activation. Softmax is done inside the loss function.

Comment: Apparently that was the problem. Thank you.